# How to remove a limit of 100kB when highlighting a file with custom syntax?

Tags: sublime-text-3, syntax-highlighting

I have created a custom syntax file for Smalltalk/X - [smalltalk embedded with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420363/how-to-correctly-embed-another-language-into-my-current-language-defintion).

The [highlighting file](https://bitbucket.org/-tukanos-/sublime-highlighting-for-smalltalk-x/src/default/Smalltalk.sublime-syntax) is mostly correct (still needs some love, but that is out of the scope of this question).

I have encountered weird limit on file size.  Every file less than or equal **100.00kB** has corrected highlighted syntax.

Every file larger (or equal) than **100.01kB** has simple coloring.

### The question

Is there an option which would allow me to fully color larger files?  (I tried to search everywhere but could not find anything like it).

**Edit** - adding samples of the fully colored file and less colored (the difference is **1 Byte**)

The fully colored looks like this:

[image: fully colored Smalltak/X syntax]

Link for it is [here](https://anonfile.com/w8beG2fdbe/colored_Tools__ChangeSetDiffTool.st)

The improperly colored one:

[image: Not fully colored]

Link for it is [here](https://anonfile.com/x1b5Gaf9be/not_colored_Tools__ChangeSetDiffTool.st)

Comment: There should be no file size limit on the size of files that get syntax highlighted; in fact there is an open request to turn off syntax highlighting for large files because they slow performance. Can you provide some sort of link to a larger file that doesn't seem to highlight properly?

Comment: @OdatNurd I see.  That would make sense for huge files.  I have added information (screenshots with links below) to my question.

Comment: @OdatNurd any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't frequent Stack Exchange very often. Both of those files syntax highlight the same for me. However Sublime reports that it doesn't know what encoding the file is and falls back to `Windows 1252` as the encoding. Using `meld` to see what's different reports an encoding conversion error. So possibly if your encoding is set incorrectly for the file it's confusing the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @OdatNurd No worries, I'm really happy for your help.  I'll double-check the encoding and check it with `meld`.

Comment: @OdatNurd Thank you for help! The encoding issue was really the culprit.  I have fixed all files and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thank you @OdatNurd with the question!

The answer is that the encoding confused the syntax highlighting and when it it fixed everything works as expected.